# Getting abstract class error on a concrete class during ant build

Tags: java, build, ant

I'm trying to build a project and I get the below error.
I have checked the jar from which AsyncMessage is being imported and the class is concrete and not an abstract one.

```
flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage is abstract; cannot be instantiated
[javac]                             AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
[javac]                                                ^
```

Below is the full AsyncMessage class I found in the flex jar being referenced.

```
    package flex.messaging.messages;

import flex.messaging.log.Log;
import flex.messaging.util.UUIDUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public class AsyncMessage
  extends AbstractMessage
  implements SmallMessage
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3549535089417916783L;
  public static final String SUBTOPIC_HEADER_NAME = "DSSubtopic";
  private static byte CORRELATION_ID_FLAG = 1;
  private static byte CORRELATION_ID_BYTES_FLAG = 2;
  protected String correlationId;
  protected byte[] correlationIdBytes;

  public String getCorrelationId()
  {
    return this.correlationId;
  }

  public void setCorrelationId(String correlationId)
  {
    this.correlationId = correlationId;
  }

  public Message getSmallMessage()
  {
    if (getClass() == AsyncMessage.class) {
      return new AsyncMessageExt(this);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void readExternal(ObjectInput input)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
  {
    super.readExternal(input);

    short[] flagsArray = readFlags(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < flagsArray.length; i++)
    {
      short flags = flagsArray[i];
      short reservedPosition = 0;
      if (i == 0)
      {
        if ((flags & CORRELATION_ID_FLAG) != 0) {
          this.correlationId = ((String)input.readObject());
        }
        if ((flags & CORRELATION_ID_BYTES_FLAG) != 0)
        {
          this.correlationIdBytes = ((byte[])input.readObject());
          this.correlationId = UUIDUtils.fromByteArray(this.correlationIdBytes);
        }
        reservedPosition = 2;
      }
      if (flags >> reservedPosition != 0) {
        for (short j = reservedPosition; j < 6; j = (short)(j + 1)) {
          if ((flags >> j & 0x1) != 0) {
            input.readObject();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output)
    throws IOException
  {
    super.writeExternal(output);
    if (this.correlationIdBytes == null) {
      this.correlationIdBytes = UUIDUtils.toByteArray(this.correlationId);
    }
    short flags = 0;
    if ((this.correlationId != null) && (this.correlationIdBytes == null)) {
      flags = (short)(flags | CORRELATION_ID_FLAG);
    }
    if (this.correlationIdBytes != null) {
      flags = (short)(flags | CORRELATION_ID_BYTES_FLAG);
    }
    output.writeByte(flags);
    if ((this.correlationId != null) && (this.correlationIdBytes == null)) {
      output.writeObject(this.correlationId);
    }
    if (this.correlationIdBytes != null) {
      output.writeObject(this.correlationIdBytes);
    }
  }

  protected String toStringFields(int indentLevel)
  {
    String sep = getFieldSeparator(indentLevel);
    String s = sep + "clientId = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("clientId") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : this.clientId);
    s = s + sep + "correlationId = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("correlationId") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : this.correlationId);
    s = s + sep + "destination = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("destination") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : this.destination);
    s = s + sep + "messageId = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("messageId") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : this.messageId);
    s = s + sep + "timestamp = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("timestamp") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : String.valueOf(this.timestamp));
    s = s + sep + "timeToLive = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("timeToLive") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : String.valueOf(this.timeToLive));
    s = s + sep + "body = " + (Log.isExcludedProperty("body") ? "** [Value Suppressed] **" : bodyToString(this.body, indentLevel));
    s = s + super.toStringFields(indentLevel);
    return s;
  }
}
```

Still not sure why java compiler is throwing this error.
I'm using Java version 1.6 and Ant version 1.7 while building.
Please check if I'm missing anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well clearly the class you have shown us is not the one that is being compiled.

So I think that the problem is that the source code above doesn't match the compiled class that `javac` is trying to compile against.

How so?

- Maybe you have multiple versions of the `AsyncMessage` class on the
  classpath.  (Maybe two JAR files containing the same class?)
- Maybe you have changed the source code of the `AsyncMessage` class
  but not recompiled it.
- Maybe you have downloaded a different version of the source code to
  the version of the compiled code.

Generally speaking, this kind of problem indicates a build or version mix-up of some kind.

Comment: Thanks, that helped , I found a amf-serializer jar which has the abstract AsyncMessage. Have removed it and the build ran fine.